# Change iCloud account alias email address

Tags: icloud, email, apple-id

I'm trying to change my iCloud account alias email address, but I couldn't find any way to do it.

As you can see below, this account's Apple ID is [name@email.com](http://#) and it's alias email is [anothername@icloud.com](http://#). I'd like to change the actual alias email to [name@icloud.com](http://#), so it has the same name as Apple ID.

[image]

I've already tried to go on **Edit**, but it only allows me to change the Apple ID (main email) and an option to add more emails. Nothing regarding the iCloud email, such as deleting it and creating another one.

Is there any way to achieve the desired?

Thank in advance,
Luiz.

Comment: There's several questions on this site about changing/updating icloud email address.  You can search for them and review the answers.  Have any of those worked for you?

Comment: I've seen many, but none of them shows how to change the [@icloud.com](http://#) email (alias). Most of them shows how to change the Apple ID (main email).

Comment: I don't believe you can change an alias.  You can up to 3 alias' and turn them off/on.  Have you tried adding one and deleting the one you don't want?

Comment: I'd even try to do it, but I need another @icloud.com email to add. Is there any way to create this email inside the account?

Comment: Take a look at [this Apple page](https://support.apple.com/kb/ph2622?locale=en_US) and see if it helps.  I'm not certain this is an answer so I'm clarifying your question first.  If it works, I can add it as an answer.

Comment: Thank you for your attention, but it didn't work. I even tried to add another alias to delete the old one, but it's not possible; I can only delete the recently created.

Comment: Sorry it didn't work.  You might need to contact Apple if nothing else will work.

Comment: I searched more now and I guess that the answer I wanted is not a option, at least by now.

Comment: But as I said above, thank you for your attention!!

Answer (score 1):

I just got off the phone with Apple support for this exact question. Short answer: it can't be done.

Once you create an iCloud email account, that account can't be changed or removed from your Apple ID. The only way to delete the email account would be to delete the entire Apple ID account.